# Field separator part of a column - incorrect parsing unix

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I want to do a check the number of columns in a CSV file before processing it. The problem is that the delimiter (comma) also occurs in the text of some fields and because of that I cannot parse it correctly and I receive too many columns.

Eg:

```
~new file: 12345~,~125.5~,,,~ example (45), case (20)~,,
```

7 columns

1. `~new file: 12345~`
2. `~125.5~`
3. *empty*
4. *empty*
5. `~ example (45), case (20)~`
6. *empty*
7. *empty*

The problem is the comma inside `~example (45), case (20)~` in 5<sup>th</sup> column.

I tried to replace delimiter `,` with `;` using `sed` but I had to do more than one iteration.

I would like a general rule that will match multiple cases with a more optimal approach.

Please note that `~` is a field quoting character (so `a, b, c, d` is four fields, but `a, ~b, c~, d` are three fields, one of which is `b, c`).

Sample:

```
~new file: 12345~,~125.5~,,,~ example (45), case (20)~,,
~file (54) ~,,~5.5~,,~ this is a sample.~,,~end, end~
~line 3~,~3.6~,~0.0~,~hello~,~hello, world~,~6.7~,~end of line~
```

The expected output:

```
~new file: 12345~;~125.5~;;;~ example (45), case (20)~;;
~file (54) ~;;~5.5~;;~ this is a sample.~;;~end, end~
~line 3~;~3.6~;~0.0~;~hello~;~hello, world~;~6.7~;~end of line~
```

Comment: How do you know which commas are part of the data and which are field separators? Proper CSV uses double quotes to surround such fields.

Comment: This is a txt file that is extracted from an application and the separteur  when the extract was done was set to be comma.

Comment: @MathewLinton. Thank you Mat, Are columns 3 4 6 7 empty in all the rows in your data? if not and I assume NOT, then the command column is more than enough. If YES then you don't have seven columns and the command `column` is more than enough ;-)

Comment: It looks like the ~ character is the quoting character (so `~hello, world~` is one field). Is that correct?

Comment: @Goro.In your example you remove all ','. In column 5th I want ',' since is the column value ~ example (45), case (20)~ and I don't want to alter the data.

Comment: @roima.yes it is!

Comment: @MathewLinton you didn't answer my question.  Are columns 3 4 6 7 empty in all the rows in your data? Would you please add more rows. this will make our task more efficient and we will help you more efficiently instead of guessing.

Comment: @iGoro. I added another line in the example. To reply to your question, not always the columns 3, 4, 6, 7 are null

Comment: @Mathew Linton thank you so much Matt. this is helpful, please notice the last line is 8 columns not 7, see my tweaks to the answer below, by the way do you need the `~` we can strip it out.

Comment: @MathewLinton check [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474614/72456) below, that's what you exactly need?

Comment: @sddgob. I added the expected output as example. I want to be able to change the delimiter without changing the values between ~... ~

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a CSV file that is using comma as field delimiters and tilde as quoting character.

Using a proper CSV parser, like the one provided by the `Text::CSV` Perl module:

```
perl -MText::CSV -e 'print scalar(@{Text::CSV->new({quote_char=>"~"})->getline(\*STDIN)})' <file.csv
```

This would read the first line of the CSV file `file.csv` and print the number of columns in it.  We instantiate a parser that understands that the quote character is a tilde before reading the first line with this parser.  The `getline()` method on this parser would read a line from the given filehandle and return a reference to an array of data, one item per parsed column. The `print scalar(...)` is a fairly common way to print the length of an array in Perl.

Another way, using the [CSVKit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/) command line CSV parser toolkit:

```
csvstat -n -q '~' <file.csv | wc -l
```

or equivalently, using long options,

```
csvstat --names --quotechar '~' <file.csv | wc -l
```

This would likewise read the first line of the input file and return a listing of the headers (the first line of a CSV file usually contains column headers), one per line.  The `wc -l` counts the number of lines returned.

The `csvstat` command by itself (without the `wc -l`) would return

```
  1: new file: 12345
  2: 125.5
  3:
  4:
  5:  example (45), case (20)
  6:
  7:
```

---

When you later parse the CSV file, I suggest that you use one of these approaches, or look for a proper parser in the programming language that you are most used to. `awk` and `sed` may be used on *simple* CSV data, but in this case your data is using some of the CSV format features that these tools would have difficulties to cope with without taking great care.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the revised question:**

```
sed -r 's/(~[^~]*~)?,/\1;/g' infile
~new file: 12345~;~125.5~;;;~ example (45), case (20)~;;
~file (54) ~;;~5.5~;;~ this is a sample.~;;~end; end~
~line 3~;~3.6~;~0.0~;~hello~;~hello, world~;~6.7~;~end of line~
```

replace all `~...~,` with `~...~;` where `~...~` can be optional.

---

To counting the number of columns in each line, with `awk` you could do:

```
awk -F, '{ gsub(/~[^~]*~/,""); print NF }' infile
```

for an input like:

```
~new file: 12345~,~125.5~,,,~ example (45), case (20)~,,
,~125.5~,,,~ example (45), case (20)~
```

It will return:

```
7
5
```

In `gsub(/~[^~]*~/,"")`, we are replacing every pattern started from a `~` till the next  `~` seen (like `~...~`) with empty string; see below:

```
awk -F, '{ gsub(/~[^~]*~/,""); print $0 }' infile
,,,,,,
,,,,
```

This assume that there is no inner `~` like `,~some~thing~,` in your input.

then `print NF` will print the number of fields according to the specified filed separator `-F` .

Answer (score 0):

`,` is the columns delimiter... I would just run the command `column` as follows:

```
column -s',' -t -o',' original_data.txt > output.csv
```

Explanation:

```
 -t, --table              create a table
 -s, --separator <string> possible table delimiters
 -o, --output-separator <string>
```

output:

```
cat output.csv 

~new file: 12345~,~125.5~,     ,       ,~ example (45)      , case (20)~,     ,
~file (54) ~     ,       ,~5.5~,       ,~ this is a sample.~,           ,~end , end~
~line 3~         ,~3.6~  ,~0.0~,~hello~,~hello              , world~    ,~6.7~,~end of line~
```

*Notice* how the comma in the output.csv file created borders between the columns.

If you would like to get rid of the `~`, you can use `sed` or `tr` after `column` something like:

```
column -s',' -t -o',' original_data.txt | tr -d "~" > output.csv
```

output

```
cat output.csv 

new file: 12345,125.5,     ,       , example (45)      , case (20),     ,
file (54)      ,       ,5.5,       , this is a sample.,           ,end , end
line 3         ,3.6  ,0.0,hello,hello              , world    ,6.7,end of line
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Here `~ example (45), case (20)~` is a single column but column is splitting in into two columns. I see the format of values in each column is `,~...~,` where comma also can be within a filed like in `,~something with comma, and rest~,` for non empty fields. it's the `~` inplace of quote  `"`

Comment: No, we have 7 columns. This is an example of the output that can be used: ~new file: 12345~;~125.5~;;;~ example (45), case(20)~;;

Comment: I amended the question with each column value